# Get each item from a list and compare it with a different one

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a piece of code, which should take a item name from a JSON, then compare it against a price list. If the name is there then it will find the price and add it to a listview. The problem with that is if I tried to add a foreach loop there, then it throws me a error. Here's my code:

```
JObject tokenJson2 = JObject.Parse(json2);
foreach (var data2 in tokenJson2["response"])
{
  var item = data2.ToArray()
                  .SingleOrDefault(x => ((JProperty)x).Name == name.ToString()) as JProperty;

  if (item != null)
  { 
   //DoSomething 
  }
}
```

Here is the error I get:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty'.

Here is the tokenJson2 data: [Link](https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetAllLowestListPrices/v1/?appid=730)

Comment: Maybe you can add an example Json string.

Comment: Can you maybe give me a suggestion where to upload it?

Comment: The content of json2 would be enough. If it is too big/long one example entry would be enough and you could post under the question.

Comment: I was able the link where I'm grabbing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your (kind of unusual) JSON structure, "response" is a `JProperty` with value being `JObject`, containing multiple `JProperty` elements with the name being the `JProperty.Name` and value being `JObject` with "price" and "quantity" properties.

It can be iterated this way:

```
var response = (JObject)tokenJson2.Property("response").Value;
foreach (var item in response.Properties())
{
    var name = item.Name;
    var data = (JObject)item.Value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your json is in this style

```
{"NameCol"="N1", "response" : [{"price":"22"}, {"price":24}, ..... {....}]
```

I am using Newtonsoft library for this purpose. Every `data2` in loop will contain single object like `{"price":"22"}`

```
foreach (var data2 in (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)tokenJson2["response"])
{
      string name = "";
      if(tokenJson2.TryParseValue("NameCol", name))
      {
        string NameFromJSON ="";
        //This line will convert {"price":"22"} to dictionary
        Dictionary<string, object> data2_dict = 
             JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(data2.ToString());
        if(data2_dict["name"] == name)
        {
             //DO SOME THING HERE
        }   
      }          
 }
```

Comment: For me it said that it has problems converting it dictionary

Comment: You can convert it to relevant object which has matching properties.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what you mean? Here is the full error though: Error converting value "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'. Path '', line 1, position 45.

Comment: I am expecting your jSon as `[{"name":"N1", "price":"22"},{"name":"N2", "price":24}, ..... {....}]`. The above code can convert this jSon to dictionary.

Comment: Hey, I added the json there as well. The item name is in a root object.

Comment: was there some thing to help you above in my post?

Comment: Is there possible to change it somehow so it could take the "name" from a root object?

Comment: Check the modified answer plz

Comment: How is your tokenJson2 defined? for me it's a JObject and JObject.Parse

Answer (score 0):

u can use SelectTokens..

```
        JToken[] tokens = tokenJson2.SelectTokens(string.Format("response.{0}", name)).ToArray();
        Array.ForEach<JToken>(tokens, (token) => {
            //DoSomething 
        });
```

Comment: Hey hmm I can't get your code working? Here is the error: Additional information: Unexpected character while parsing path:

Comment: i can't open your json link. can u put here?

Comment: i cant open. i'm under proxy

Comment: Oh, I can't put it here because it's big as hell